# Find Lotus Notes installations by C

Tags: c, winapi, lotus-notes

I would like to list all Lotus Notes installations on my computer. How can I do that by using C and Win32 API?

Comment: My application uses Lotus Notes API and I would like to check whether correct version of Lotus Notes installed on user's computer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an easier time searching the registry for Lotus Notes keys. One of the keys tells the version installed